# Не получается создать запись в связанную модель AR

Tags: php, yii, activerecord

Есть у меня модель News и модель Files. В News прописана связь `'files'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Files', 'news_id')`.
Мне нужно получить одну новость, сделать с ней нужные мне вещи и добавить файл в связанную таблицу files. Пробую делать вот так:

```
$model=News::model()->findByPk($_GET['id']);
$model->files = new Files;
$model->files->name = "Имя файла";
$model->save()
```

Редактировать полученную новость удается, а вот запись в таблицу files не добавляется. Подскажите, что делаю не верно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите таким образом сохранять, то у вас видимо не переопределен afterSave основной модели, чтобы сохранить связную модель, пример yiiframework.ru/doc/cookbook/ru/model.save.related.data

Comment: Из этого рецепта не понятно как по аналогии сделать

Comment: Просто в моделе News переопредлите метод afterSave по аналогии с примером, только у вас вместо массива будет одна запись $this->files->news_id=$this->id; $this->files->save();

Comment: Переопределил. Если отобразить объект $this->files, то видно, что атрибутам значения присвоены: `["_attributes":"CActiveRecord":private]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    int(11111)
    ["news_id"]=>
    int(23)
  }`, но save() по прежнему не сохраняет в бд

Comment: Посмотрите, что выводит при сохранении если это добавить в afterSave() `var_dump($this->files->save()); var_dump($this->files->getErrors());`

Comment: Вообще ничего не выводит

Comment: Разместите код двух моделей на каком-нибудь сервисе, чтобы можно было взглянуть что у вас получилось в итоге.